# autocompletion discord.py bots command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a bot using discord.py and would like to implement command autocompletion (using tab) and make that bot's commands distinct from others.
I have seen that all of this is already implemented in most of the "ready" bots.

For example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf9R7.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are a new feature in Discord called [Slash Commands](https://blog.discord.com/slash-commands-are-here-8db0a385d9e6?gi=c04ee288c12c). Admittedly, these are a bit harder to work with than typical Discord commands, but are much more rewarding due to the autocomplete and separation from bots.

If you're working on implementing this in Python, I can point you in the direction of [this library](https://github.com/discord-py-slash-commands/discord-py-interactions) written for exactly your use case. It extends the typical discord.py library and adds nice, new features; slash commands being one of them.

Comment: Thank you! You have been of invaluable help

Comment: No worries @17leonAg29, if I've been helpful, I'd appreciate if you would mark my answer as correct using the checkmark!

Comment: Should note that standard discord.py has slash commands (and fancy hybrid commands) built-in now as of v2